# Alternative to multiple identical IDs in the same HTML document

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I know that repeated use of identical IDs in one HTML document is a bad practice.

How can I avoid this, if I have elements performing the same functions, and to which I need to get quick access?

For example:

```
<form id='dialog_setting_dns-form'>
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input name="address" id="address"/>
</form>
<form id='dialog_static'>
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input name="address" id="address"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use class selector instead.

Comment: use class instead of id in that situation

Comment: It's not actually bad practice. It's totally wrong.

Comment: You can use same class on elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use class instead of id in that situation

```
<form id='dialog_setting_dns-form'>
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input name="address" class="address" />
</form>

<form id='dialog_static'>
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input name="address" class="address" />
</form>
```

You would select by class in jQuery with `$('.address')` as opposed to using an id `$('#address')`.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is why classes are for in html tags.

With jquery select them by class and iterate through them.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is not a good answer. It is useful to post modified code not just explain in words.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class instat on all of these elements and select it then.

*Pure JavaScript:*

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("MyClassName");
```

*jQuery:*

```
var elemens = $(".MyClassName");
```